# Map pandas Series to list membership

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say that I have the following Series, `dtype('O')`:

```
s = pd.Series(list('abcde'))
```

And the following lists (groups):

```
group1 = list('ab')
group2 = list('cd')
group3 = list('xy')
```

I would like to map `s` to a new Series based on group memberships, filling with `np.nan` in the case of no membership.  Result:

```
res
Out[17]: 
0    group1
1    group1
2    group2
3    group2
4       nan
dtype: object
```

I'm looking for a much more pythonic way of doing so than using repeats of `np.where`:

```
res = pd.Series(np.where(s.isin(group1), 'group1',
                         np.where(s.isin(group2), 'group2',
                         np.where(s.isin(group3), 'group3',
                         np.nan))))
```

Ideally this would mean doing something like specifying the collection of lists as a single iterable, since in my real problem I have a much larger number of groups.  `res` can be dtype `O` or `categorical`.

What I've tried:

- The above example with `np.where`, which works but is overly verbose.
- Creating `dict(zip(['group1', 'group2', 'group3'], [group1, group2, group3]))`.  Stuck there.

I have a feeling this might be a duplicate but I wasn't able to find at first attempt.

Note: **the group lists will always be disjoint.**

Comment: I didn't have a chance to reply to your comment earlier. I think your best bet is to construct that mapping at the beginning but I don't know how you are getting those lists. In any case, if efficiency is an issue please feel free to unaccept. People are much more likely to work on alternatives if the question isn't closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to restructure the mapping.

Starting from your dict (`dict(zip(['group1', 'group2', 'group3'], [group1, group2, group3]))`):

```
d = {'group1': list('ab'), 'group2': list('cd'), 'group3': list('xy')}
```

The reversed one, assuming disjoint lists, will be:

```
reversed_map = {v: k for k, lst in d.items() for v in lst}
```

Now, you can just use map:

```
s.map(reversed_map)
Out[19]: 
0    group1
1    group1
2    group2
3    group2
4       NaN
dtype: object
```